# FOSS Double-Entry Accounting Software with import/export to open financial file formats (bookkeeping)

Tags: open-source, finance, accounting

Are there any open-source accounting software projects whoose software has native support to *both* import *and* export to common, open, standard financial file formats?

Popular open financial file formats include:

1. [Open Financial Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Financial_Exchange) (`.ofc` or `.ofx`)
2. [eXtensible Business Reporting Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBRL) (`.xbrl`)

GNU Cash is a popular choice, but the fact that it can't export to a standard format that's actually used by other software is a deal breaker.

Are there any FOSS accounting software solutions that can *both* import *and* export all of their data in a popular, open file format?

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_accounting_software

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [FireFly III](https://github.com/firefly-iii/firefly-iii). It allows importing from and exporting to [csv](https://docs.firefly-iii.org/firefly-iii/exporting-data/), so you may be able to get a converter to other file formats.